# Can I disallow delete queries on all instances of a resource in tastypie?

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

Let's say I have a resource named res, its instances are accessible thourgh the url:
.../api/res/<res_id>/

I'd like the clients to be allowed to send delete queries on specific instances (so on the above url), but not to delete all the instances at one time by sending a DELETE on the root url for the resource 'res' (.../api/res/), how can I configure tastypie for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement your own authorization as described in [the documentation](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authorization):

```
class CustomAuthorization(Authorization):
    def delete_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        raise Unauthorized("You cannot delete multiple objects at once.")
        # or 
        return []
```

Raising an error will return a HTTP 401 status code, while returning an empty list will return a HTTP 200 status code. Both will not delete any items.

You can create a subclass of any of the default authorization classes to inherit their behaviour, or you can create your own class and implement all required methods.

**EDIT**: As you found out, the easiest way to do this is to specify the `list_allowed_methods` attribute in the resource's Meta:

```
class MyResource(models.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch'] # no 'delete'
```

This will set the allowed methods for requests for multiple objects. It's counterpart `detail_allowed_methods` will set the allowed methods for single object requests.

Comment: Weirdly, it didn't worked, even when overriding delete_detail, the functions where just not called, it behaved exactly the same as when setting authorization=Authorization() (instead of CustomAuthorization()).
Even more surprinsing, removing 'delete' from list_allowed_methods make it have exactly the desired behaviour( with authorization = Authorization()) : I can delete only on an id, which shouldn't be the case (I should not be able to delete at all).

Comment: That first thing is weird. Have you properly set the `authorization` attribute in your resource's `Meta` class to an instance of your custom class? It should behave as desired. Anyway, that second way is actually the best way to go, the `%s_allowed_methods` are actually 2 separate lists, one for single objects and the other (`list_allowed_methods`) for multiple objects.

Comment: Yes I'm quite sure I did it correctly.
Oh great then, the 'list' part in the name is confusing about what it refers to, I thought it meant "the list of allowed methods", thanks for the insight.